# Poner resultados de consulta en un array JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Amigos, a ver si me pueden ayudar a resolver este dilema.

Yo estoy obteniendo un JSON desde una consulta a la base de datos en la que intervienen varias tablas. Ese JSON es presentado luego en una app Android.

Quisiera presentar en mi JSON una clave llamada `salmodia` y dentro de ella una clave llamada `salmos` que debería contener un array con todos los salmos que encuentre (son por lo general tres salmos, cada uno de ellos con elementos que provienen de otras tablas... pero en ocasiones son más de tres salmos). La idea es precisamente que dentro del array me cree la cantidad de salmos que encuentre en la consulta, sean tres, sean seis, sea uno...

Para no enrollarme demasiado, esa parte del JSON quisiera presentarla así:

```
            "salmodia": {
                "tipo": 1
            },
            "salmos":
                [{
                        "orden": "1",
                        "antifona": "Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.",
                        "ref": "Salmo 118, 17-24",
                        "tema": "",
                        "intro": "",
                        "parte": "",
                        "salmo": "Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros."
                    },

                    {
                        "orden": "2",
                        "antifona": "Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad.",
                        "ref": "Salmo 24",
                        "tema": "Oración por toda clase de necesidades",
                        "intro": "La esperanza no defrauda.~(Rm 5, 5)",
                        "parte": "1",
                        "salmo": "A ti, Señor, levanto mi alma;_Dios mío, en ti confío, no quede yo defraudado,_que no triunfen de mí mis enemigos;_pues los que esperan en ti no quedan defraudados,_mientras que el fracaso malogra a los traidores.§Señor, enséñame tus caminos,_instrúyeme en tus sendas:_haz que camine con lealtad;_enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador,_y todo el día te estoy esperando.§Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura_y tu misericordia son eternas;_no te acuerdes de los pecados_ni de las maldades de mi juventud;_acuérdate de mí con misericordia,_por tu bondad, Señor.§El Señor es bueno y es recto,_y enseña el camino a los pecadores;_hace caminar a los humildes con rectitud,_enseña su camino a los humildes.§Las sendas del Señor son misericordia y lealtad_para los que guardan su alianza y sus mandatos._Por el honor de tu nombre, Señor,_perdona mis culpas, que son muchas."
                    },

                    {
                        "orden": "3",
                        "antifona": "Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.",
                        "ref": "",
                        "tema": "",
                        "intro": "",
                        "parte": "2",
                        "salmo": "¿Hay alguien que tema al Señor?_Él le enseñará el camino escogido:_su alma vivirá feliz,_su descendencia poseerá la tierra.§El Señor se confía con sus fieles_y les da a conocer su alianza._Tengo los ojos puestos en el Señor,_porque él saca mis pies de la red.§Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y ten piedad de mí,_que estoy solo y afligido._Ensancha mi corazón oprimido y_sácame de mis tribulaciones.§Mira mis trabajos y mis penas_y perdona todos mis pecados,_mira cuántos son mis enemigos,_que me detestan con odio cruel.§Guarda mi vida y líbrame,_no quede yo defraudado de haber acudido a ti._La inocencia y la rectitud me protegerán,_porque espero en ti.§Salva, ¡oh Dios!, a Israel_de todos sus peligros."

                    }
                ],
```

El problema es que dentro del objeto `salmos`, las claves que vemos en cada uno: `orden, antifona, ref`, etc provienen de tablas relacionadas entre sí.

Actualmente yo estoy organizando esa parte *a mano*, limitándola a tres salmos... pero el código fallará en la App cuando no sean tres salmos. Por eso mi idea es meter todo en un array para poder leerlo dentro de un bucle sin preocuparme de cuántos salmos haya.

La consulta ahora mismo está así:

```
SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsg.orden, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') AS ordenes, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsa.antifonas, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') AS antifonas, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhs.salmo_ref, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') AS salmos_ref, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhst.tema, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') as temas,
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsi.intro, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') as intros,
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhsg.parte, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') AS partes, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(lhs.salmo, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') as salmos ...
```

Lo que hace la consulta es obtener **por separado** cada uno de los elementos, por ejemplo:

- En la columna `ordenes`, los tres números del orden de cada salmo: `1|2|3`
- En la columna `antifonas`, las tres antífonas: `Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.|Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad.|Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.
- En la columna `salmos_ref`, las tres referencias: `Salmo 118, 17-24|Salmo 24|`

Luego hago un `explode` de cada elemento y construyo tres salmos a mano, quedando así en el JSON:

```
            "salmodia": {
                "tipo": 1,
                "salmos": {

                    "s1": {
                        "orden": "1",
                        "antifona": "Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.",
                        "ref": "Salmo 118, 17-24",
                        "tema": "",
                        "intro": "",
                        "parte": "",
                        "salmo": "Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros."
                    },

                    "s2": {
                        "orden": "2",
                        "antifona": "Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad.",
                        "ref": "Salmo 24",
                        "tema": "Oración por toda clase de necesidades",
                        "intro": "La esperanza no defrauda.~(Rm 5, 5)",
                        "parte": "1",
                        "salmo": "A ti, Señor, levanto mi alma;_Dios mío, en ti confío, no quede yo defraudado,_que no triunfen de mí mis enemigos;_pues los que esperan en ti no quedan defraudados,_mientras que el fracaso malogra a los traidores.§Señor, enséñame tus caminos,_instrúyeme en tus sendas:_haz que camine con lealtad;_enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador,_y todo el día te estoy esperando.§Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura_y tu misericordia son eternas;_no te acuerdes de los pecados_ni de las maldades de mi juventud;_acuérdate de mí con misericordia,_por tu bondad, Señor.§El Señor es bueno y es recto,_y enseña el camino a los pecadores;_hace caminar a los humildes con rectitud,_enseña su camino a los humildes.§Las sendas del Señor son misericordia y lealtad_para los que guardan su alianza y sus mandatos._Por el honor de tu nombre, Señor,_perdona mis culpas, que son muchas."
                    },

                    "s3": {
                        "orden": "3",
                        "antifona": "Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.",
                        "ref": "",
                        "tema": "",
                        "intro": "",
                        "parte": "2",
                        "salmo": "¿Hay alguien que tema al Señor?_Él le enseñará el camino escogido:_su alma vivirá feliz,_su descendencia poseerá la tierra.§El Señor se confía con sus fieles_y les da a conocer su alianza._Tengo los ojos puestos en el Señor,_porque él saca mis pies de la red.§Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y ten piedad de mí,_que estoy solo y afligido._Ensancha mi corazón oprimido y_sácame de mis tribulaciones.§Mira mis trabajos y mis penas_y perdona todos mis pecados,_mira cuántos son mis enemigos,_que me detestan con odio cruel.§Guarda mi vida y líbrame,_no quede yo defraudado de haber acudido a ti._La inocencia y la rectitud me protegerán,_porque espero en ti.§Salva, ¡oh Dios!, a Israel_de todos sus peligros."
                    }
                }
            },
```

¿Cómo podría poner todos los salmos y sus elementos en un array?

PD: No he dado más detalles sobre la base de datos y las tablas para no enrollarme demasiado. De todos modos, si hace falta que agregue alguna información lo pueden decir en comentario.

---

#### Más detalles importantes

- En la consulta intervienen otros datos de otras tablas que son únicos, por lo que me interesa tener **una sola fila** con los resultados.
- El código PHP en el que hago `explode` de los resultados obtenidos es este:

  ```
          $orden=$row["ordenes"];
          $tema=$row["temas"];
          $ref=$row["salmos_ref"];
          $parte=$row["partes"];
          $intro=$row["intros"];
          $salmo=$row["salmos"];

          $antifonas = explode("|", $antifona);
          $ordenes = explode("|", $orden);
          $temas = explode("|", $tema);
          $refs = explode("|", $ref);
          $partes = explode("|", $parte);
          $intros = explode("|", $intro);
          $salmos = explode("|", $salmo);
          $orden0=$ordenes[0];
          $ant0=$antifonas[0]; $ref0=$refs[0]; $tema0=$temas[0]; $intro0=$intros[0]; $parte0=$partes[0]; $sal0=$salmos[0];

          $orden1=$ordenes[1];
          $ant1=$antifonas[1]; $ref1=$refs[1]; $tema1=$temas[1]; $intro1=$intros[1]; $parte1=$partes[1]; $sal1=$salmos[1];

          $orden2=$ordenes[2];
          $ant2=$antifonas[2]; $ref2=$refs[2]; $tema2=$temas[2]; $intro2=$intros[2]; $parte2=$partes[2]; $sal2=$salmos[2];
  ```

Luego, cada dato es puesto *a mano*  en el JSON final.

Comment: Si simplemente no haces uso de `GROUP BY` (ni `GROUP_CONCAT`, ni `explode`) y haces un `fetchAll`, deberías tener solucionado el problema, es decir, los registros no se agruparían y obtendrías el arreglo que buscas

Comment: Gracias @Marcos. La cuestión es que en la consulta intervienen más datos de otras tablas y esos datos son únicos. La idea de agrupar surgió porque quiero obtener una sola fila de resultados, si dejo de agrupar voy a obtener tantas filas como salmos haya.

Comment: Entiendo, considera actualizar la pregunta añadiendo este detalle. ¿Podrías agregar en la pregunta el código donde haces `explode` de los datos?

Comment: Lo he agregado al final @Marcos.

Comment: Te soy sincero... al ver el código... desde mi punto de vista, lo mejor sería hacer 2 consultas. El resultado sería mas limpio y a prueba de errores, ya que si alguno de lo salmos incluye un `|` (`pipe`) el resultado sería erroneo.

Comment: @Marcos el contenido que hay en la BD está estrictamente controlado para que eso no ocurra... tu primer comentario me dio una idea que estoy probando y creo que puede funcionar... ahora comento.

Comment: @Marcos creo que podría lograrlo del siguiente modo en una sola fila: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
      lhsg.orden, '_',
      lhsa.antifonas, '_', 
      COALESCE(lhs.salmo_ref, ''),'_', 
      COALESCE(lhst.tema,''), '_', 
      COALESCE(lhsi.intro,''), '_', 
      COALESCE(lhsg.parte,''), '_'
      ORDER BY  orden 
      SEPARATOR '|'
      ) AS salmos`...

Comment: Obtengo una columna así: `1_Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad._Salmo 118, 17-24____|2_Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad._Salmo 24_Oración por toda clase de necesidades_La esperanza no defrauda.~(Rm 5, 5)_1_|3_Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.____2_`, la cual podría trabajar para construir el array que quiero usando los separadores de cada salmo `|` y los separadores para cada elemento dentro de un salmo `_`. Trabajaré el resultado y comento...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73525/discussion-between-marcos-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la idea es no hacer mas de una consulta, quizás una mejor solución podría ser aramar un `JSON` directamente en la consulta.

Así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT ...
  CONCAT('[', # Empezamos la definición del array
    GROUP_CONCAT( #Agrupamos los registros separados por coma
      CONCAT('{', # Armamos el objeto "salmo"
        '"orden": "', COALESCE(lhsg.orden, ''), '", ',
        # Usamos REPLACE para escapar las comillas dobles que pudieran existir
        '"antifona": "', REPLACE(COALESCE(lhsa.antifonas, ''), '"', '\\"'), '", ',
        '"ref": "', COALESCE(lhs.salmo_ref, ''), '" ,',
        '"tema": "', REPLACE(COALESCE(lhst.tema, ''), '"', '\\"'), '", ',
        '"intro": "', REPLACE(COALESCE(lhsi.intro, ''), '"', '\\"'), '", ',
        '"parte": "', COALESCE(lhsg.parte, ''), '", ',
        '"salmo": "', REPLACE(COALESCE(lhs.salmo, ''), '"', '\\"'), '"',
      '}')
    SEPARATOR ','), 
  ']') AS salmos 
  FROM ....
```

De esta forma, con `PHP` para obtener un `array`, solo deberías hacer:

```
$row['salmos'] = json_decode($row['salmos'], true);
```

---

## Update

Otra opción siguiendo lo comentado, podría ser:

- Agrupar los salmos usando el separador `|`
- Agregar un separador, por ejemplo `⊥`, para separar los datos
- Agregar el nombre del dato, un separador (por ejemplo `⟶`) y el valor del dato, para poder identificarlos.

#### Ejemplo

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    'orden', '⟶', COALESCE(lhsg.orden, ''), '⊥',
    'antifona', '⟶', COALESCE(lhsa.antifonas, ''), '⊥',
    'ref', '⟶', COALESCE(lhs.salmo_ref, ''), '⊥',
    'tema', '⟶', COALESCE(lhst.tema, ''), '⊥',
    'intro', '⟶', COALESCE(lhsi.intro, ''), '⊥',
    'parte', '⟶', COALESCE(lhsg.parte, ''), '⊥',
    'salmo', '⟶', COALESCE(lhs.salmo, ''))
  ORDER BY orden
  SEPARATOR '|') AS salmos
FROM ...
```

Y en `PHP` podrías parsearlos así:

```
$arrSalmos = array_map(function ($info) {

    $salmo = [];
    array_map(function ($dato) {

      list($campo, $valor) = explode('⟶', $dato); // Separamos por `⟶`
      $salmo[$campo] = $valor;
    }, explode('⊥', $info)); // Separamos por `⊥`

    return $salmo;
}, explode('|', $row["salmos"])); // Separamos por `|`
```

Comment: Marcos el JSON es mucho más grande, por lo que no veo viable construir todo el JSON en la consulta SQL. Además hago algún trabajo de verificación con algunos valores antes de sacarlos definitivamente en el JSON. Haciendo una concatenación con dos separadores (uno para cada salmo y otro para cada elemento dentro del salmo) he podido obtener el array como lo quiero... ahora estoy viendo cómo pasarlo a un json como he indicado en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano, no me queda claro lo que comentas. "_¿Cómo podría poner todos los salmos y sus elementos en un array?_", esta es una de las preguntas. ¿Podrías indicar cual es el resultado que buscas? Por lo que comentas, la solución a tu problema esta en el `PHP` y no has compartido todo el código relevante como para recibir una respuesta acorde.

Comment: Haciendo la consulta así: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
   COALESCE(lhsg.orden, ''),'⊥',
   COALESCE(lhsa.antifonas, ''),'⊥',  
   COALESCE(lhs.salmo_ref, '') ,'⊥', 
   COALESCE(lhst.tema, '') ,'⊥', 
   COALESCE(lhsi.intro, ''),'⊥', 
   COALESCE(lhsg.parte, ''),'⊥',
   COALESCE(lhs.salmo, '') ORDER BY  orden SEPARATOR '|') AS salmos FROM...` obtengo los valores con dos separadores. Luego uso una función de PHP para obtener un array por cada salmo. En la pregunta muestro al principio cómo querría el JSON final. Lo planteado en esta pregunta se podría dar por resuelto escribiendo la consulta...

Comment: ... como he indicado en el último comentario. El código con el que organizo los datos obtenidos es este: `$salmos=$row["salmos"];
$arrSalmos = array_map (
  function ($_) {return explode ('⊥', $_);},
  explode ('|', $salmos)
);`... Ese código me da un array multidimensional dentro del cual hay un array por cada salmo con todos sus elementos. Ahora me resta convertir ese array a la parte de JSON que quiero (el modelo que indico en la pregunta). No sé si me he explicado.

Comment: @A.Cedano, la verdad, disculpa, pero no. Si *no buscabas* una forma de resolverlo usando `MySQL`, ¿porque incluir la consulta y no el `PHP`? Si buscas obtener un resultado como el incluido en la pregunta (_cosa que no esta claro *en la pregunta*_), ¿por que indicas que buscas un `array` cuando claramente `salmos` es un objeto?

Comment: Marcos no sé si me expresé mal en la pregunta. El problema era que yo tenía la consulta mal, estaba agrupando los elementos de salmos diferenciados... tu primer comentario me dio la idea de concatenar todo usando dos separadores. En la pregunta yo dije que lo quiero es que la clave `salmos` de mi JSON tenga un array dentro del cual estén los diferentes salmos con todos sus elementos, algo más o menos así: `{  
   "salmodia":{  
      "salmos":[  ]
   }
}`. Dentro de `[...]` estarían los elementos. A eso me refería con lo del array.

Comment: @A.Cedano, ahora si entiendo. A modo de sugerencia, para poder identificar cada dato, podrías concatenar en nombre del dato y un separador y así solo te quedaría hacer un `explode` mas por cada `$_`. Básicamente lo mismo que he hecho en mi respuesta, solo que yo armo un `JSON` el cual no es necesario `explode`-ar 3 veces.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73542/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-marcos).