# Convertir array de PHP en JSON con nombres de clave específicos

Tags: php, json, array

Tengo el siguiente array en PHP:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.
            [2] => Salmo 118, 17-24
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad.
            [2] => Salmo 24
            [3] => Oración por toda clase de necesidades
            [4] => La esperanza no defrauda.~(Rm 5, 5)
            [5] => 1
            [6] => A ti, Señor, levanto mi alma;_Dios mío, en ti confío, no quede yo defraudado,_que no triunfen de mí mis enemigos;_pues los que esperan en ti no quedan defraudados,_mientras que el fracaso malogra a los traidores.§Señor, enséñame tus caminos,_instrúyeme en tus sendas:_haz que camine con lealtad;_enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador,_y todo el día te estoy esperando.§Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura_y tu misericordia son eternas;_no te acuerdes de los pecados_ni de las maldades de mi juventud;_acuérdate de mí con misericordia,_por tu bondad, Señor.§El Señor es bueno y es recto,_y enseña el camino a los pecadores;_hace caminar a los humildes con rectitud,_enseña su camino a los humildes.§Las sendas del Señor son misericordia y lealtad_para los que guardan su alianza y sus mandatos._Por el honor de tu nombre, Señor,_perdona mis culpas, que son muchas.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 2
            [6] => ¿Hay alguien que tema al Señor?_Él le enseñará el camino escogido:_su alma vivirá feliz,_su descendencia poseerá la tierra.§El Señor se confía con sus fieles_y les da a conocer su alianza._Tengo los ojos puestos en el Señor,_porque él saca mis pies de la red.§Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y ten piedad de mí,_que estoy solo y afligido._Ensancha mi corazón oprimido y_sácame de mis tribulaciones.§Mira mis trabajos y mis penas_y perdona todos mis pecados,_mira cuántos son mis enemigos,_que me detestan con odio cruel.§Guarda mi vida y líbrame,_no quede yo defraudado de haber acudido a ti._La inocencia y la rectitud me protegerán,_porque espero en ti.§Salva, ¡oh Dios!, a Israel_de todos sus peligros.
        )

)
```

Y quisiera convertirlo en un objeto JSON. Sé que existe `json_encode` para convertir arrays en JSON, pero yo quiero que mi objeto JSON quede del siguiente modo:

```
{
    "salmodia": {
        "salmos": [{
                "orden": 1,
                "antifona": "Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.",
                "ref": "Salmo 118, 17-24",
                "tema": "",
                "intro": "",
                "parte": "",
                "salmo": "Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros."
            },

            {
                "orden": 2,
                "antifona": "Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad.",
                "ref": "Salmo 24",
                "tema": "Oración por toda clase de necesidades",
                "intro": "La esperanza no defrauda.~(Rm 5, 5)",
                "parte": 1,
                "salmo": "A ti, Señor, levanto mi alma;_Dios mío, en ti confío, no quede yo defraudado,_que no triunfen de mí mis enemigos;_pues los que esperan en ti no quedan defraudados,_mientras que el fracaso malogra a los traidores.§Señor, enséñame tus caminos,_instrúyeme en tus sendas:_haz que camine con lealtad;_enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador,_y todo el día te estoy esperando.§Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura_y tu misericordia son eternas;_no te acuerdes de los pecados_ni de las maldades de mi juventud;_acuérdate de mí con misericordia,_por tu bondad, Señor.§El Señor es bueno y es recto,_y enseña el camino a los pecadores;_hace caminar a los humildes con rectitud,_enseña su camino a los humildes.§Las sendas del Señor son misericordia y lealtad_para los que guardan su alianza y sus mandatos._Por el honor de tu nombre, Señor,_perdona mis culpas, que son muchas."
            }, {
                "orden": 3,
                "antifona": "Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.",
                "ref": "",
                "tema": "",
                "intro": "",
                "parte": 2,
                "salmo": "¿Hay alguien que tema al Señor?_Él le enseñará el camino escogido:_su alma vivirá feliz,_su descendencia poseerá la tierra.§El Señor se confía con sus fieles_y les da a conocer su alianza._Tengo los ojos puestos en el Señor,_porque él saca mis pies de la red.§Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y ten piedad de mí,_que estoy solo y afligido._Ensancha mi corazón oprimido y_sácame de mis tribulaciones.§Mira mis trabajos y mis penas_y perdona todos mis pecados,_mira cuántos son mis enemigos,_que me detestan con odio cruel.§Guarda mi vida y líbrame,_no quede yo defraudado de haber acudido a ti._La inocencia y la rectitud me protegerán,_porque espero en ti.§Salva, ¡oh Dios!, a Israel_de todos sus peligros."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

He logrado traer los datos como los presento en el array, gracias a la ayuda de @Marcos en esta pregunta: [Poner resultados de consulta en un array JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/140498/29967) , pero ahora necesito que las claves `0 al 6` del array queden en un JSON como nombres de llave específicos: `orden, antifona, ref...` etc. Cabe señalar que ese orden siempre es el mismo, lo único que podría cambiar sería el número de elementos que haya dentro del array. En este caso tenemos tres salmos, pero podrían ser más o menos de tres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple con **array_combin**e dentro de un **foreach()**
Espero que te sea útil, mas información:

1. [array-combine](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-combine.php)
2. [foreach](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

**Ejemplo:**
[Link al DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf4d1fc88d5037f94a1b95b61fc9873221c7a99d)

```
$d = array(
  array(
             1,
             'Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.',
            'Salmo 118, 17-24',
             '',
             '',
             '',
            'Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.',
        ),
   array(
             2,
             'Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.',
            'Salmo 118, 17-24',
             '',
             '',
             '',
            'Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.',
        ),
   array(
             3,
             'Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.',
            'Salmo 118, 17-24',
             '',
             '',
             '',
            'Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.',
        ),

);

// set title
$key = array('orden','antifona','ref','tema','intro','parte','salmo');

// loop
foreach($d as $i => $v){
  $d[$i]=array_combine($key,$v);
}

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($d);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Resultado:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orden] => 1
            [antifona] => Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.
            [ref] => Salmo 118, 17-24
            [tema] => 
            [intro] => 
            [parte] => 
            [salmo] => Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [orden] => 2
            [antifona] => Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.
            [ref] => Salmo 118, 17-24
            [tema] => 
            [intro] => 
            [parte] => 
            [salmo] => Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [orden] => 3
            [antifona] => Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.
            [ref] => Salmo 118, 17-24
            [tema] => 
            [intro] => 
            [parte] => 
            [salmo] => Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la función [array_map()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) que devuelve un array que contiene todos los elementos de array1 después de haber aplicado la función callback a cada uno de ellos, para renombrar las claves de tu arreglo

```
$a[0] = array
        (
            0 => 1,
            1 => "Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.",
            2 => "Salmo 118, 17-24",
            3 => "",
            4 => "",
            5 => "",
            6 => "Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros."
        );

    $a[1] = array
        (
            0 => 2,
            1 => "Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad.",
            2 => "Salmo 24",
            3 => "Oración por toda clase de necesidades",
            4 => "La esperanza no defrauda.~(Rm 5, 5)",
            5 => 1,
            6 => "A ti, Señor, levanto mi alma;_Dios mío, en ti confío, no quede yo defraudado,_que no triunfen de mí mis enemigos;_pues los que esperan en ti no quedan defraudados,_mientras que el fracaso malogra a los traidores.§Señor, enséñame tus caminos,_instrúyeme en tus sendas:_haz que camine con lealtad;_enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador,_y todo el día te estoy esperando.§Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura_y tu misericordia son eternas;_no te acuerdes de los pecados_ni de las maldades de mi juventud;_acuérdate de mí con misericordia,_por tu bondad, Señor.§El Señor es bueno y es recto,_y enseña el camino a los pecadores;_hace caminar a los humildes con rectitud,_enseña su camino a los humildes.§Las sendas del Señor son misericordia y lealtad_para los que guardan su alianza y sus mandatos._Por el honor de tu nombre, Señor,_perdona mis culpas, que son muchas."
        );

    $a[2] = array
        (
            0 => 3,
            1 => "Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.",
            2 => "",
            3 => "",
            4 => "",
            5 => 2,
            6 => "¿Hay alguien que tema al Señor?_Él le enseñará el camino escogido:_su alma vivirá feliz,_su descendencia poseerá la tierra.§El Señor se confía con sus fieles_y les da a conocer su alianza._Tengo los ojos puestos en el Señor,_porque él saca mis pies de la red.§Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y ten piedad de mí,_que estoy solo y afligido._Ensancha mi corazón oprimido y_sácame de mis tribulaciones.§Mira mis trabajos y mis penas_y perdona todos mis pecados,_mira cuántos son mis enemigos,_que me detestan con odio cruel.§Guarda mi vida y líbrame,_no quede yo defraudado de haber acudido a ti._La inocencia y la rectitud me protegerán,_porque espero en ti.§Salva, ¡oh Dios!, a Israel_de todos sus peligros."
        );

$b = array_map(function($a) {
    return array(
        'orden' => $a[0],
        'antifona' => $a[1],
        'ref'=>$a[2],
        'tema'=>$a[3],
        'intro'=>$a[4],
        'parte'=>$a[5],
        'salmo'=>$a[6]
    );
}, $a);

print_r($b);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orden] => 1
            [antifona] => Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.
            [ref] => Salmo 118, 17-24
            [tema] => 
            [intro] => 
            [parte] => 
            [salmo] => Haz bien a tu siervo: viviré_y cumpliré tus palabras;_ábreme los ojos y contemplaré_las maravillas de tu voluntad;_soy un forastero en la tierra:_no me ocultes tus promesas.§Mi alma se consume, deseando_continuamente tus mandamientos;_reprendes a los soberbios,_infelices los que se apartan de tus mandatos;_aleja de mí las afrentas y el desprecio,_porque observo tus preceptos.§Aunque los nobles se sientan a murmurar de mí,_tu siervo medita tus leyes;_tus preceptos son mi delicia,_tus decretos son mis consejeros.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [orden] => 2
            [antifona] => Haz, Señor, que camine con lealtad.
            [ref] => Salmo 24
            [tema] => Oración por toda clase de necesidades
            [intro] => La esperanza no defrauda.~(Rm 5, 5)
            [parte] => 1
            [salmo] => A ti, Señor, levanto mi alma;_Dios mío, en ti confío, no quede yo defraudado,_que no triunfen de mí mis enemigos;_pues los que esperan en ti no quedan defraudados,_mientras que el fracaso malogra a los traidores.§Señor, enséñame tus caminos,_instrúyeme en tus sendas:_haz que camine con lealtad;_enséñame, porque tú eres mi Dios y Salvador,_y todo el día te estoy esperando.§Recuerda, Señor, que tu ternura_y tu misericordia son eternas;_no te acuerdes de los pecados_ni de las maldades de mi juventud;_acuérdate de mí con misericordia,_por tu bondad, Señor.§El Señor es bueno y es recto,_y enseña el camino a los pecadores;_hace caminar a los humildes con rectitud,_enseña su camino a los humildes.§Las sendas del Señor son misericordia y lealtad_para los que guardan su alianza y sus mandatos._Por el honor de tu nombre, Señor,_perdona mis culpas, que son muchas.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [orden] => 3
            [antifona] => Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y sácame de mis tribulaciones, que estoy solo y afligido.
            [ref] => 
            [tema] => 
            [intro] => 
            [parte] => 2
            [salmo] => ¿Hay alguien que tema al Señor?_Él le enseñará el camino escogido:_su alma vivirá feliz,_su descendencia poseerá la tierra.§El Señor se confía con sus fieles_y les da a conocer su alianza._Tengo los ojos puestos en el Señor,_porque él saca mis pies de la red.§Mírame, ¡oh Dios!, y ten piedad de mí,_que estoy solo y afligido._Ensancha mi corazón oprimido y_sácame de mis tribulaciones.§Mira mis trabajos y mis penas_y perdona todos mis pecados,_mira cuántos son mis enemigos,_que me detestan con odio cruel.§Guarda mi vida y líbrame,_no quede yo defraudado de haber acudido a ti._La inocencia y la rectitud me protegerán,_porque espero en ti.§Salva, ¡oh Dios!, a Israel_de todos sus peligros.
        )

)
```

Aqui el codigo funcional: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0155c3cf230b32f649026b7562e670b674fd22f7

Comment: Juan tu código funciona perfectamente, pero la respuesta de @Sergio me pareció que implementa un código más simple. De todos modos quería que conste que de la manera que dices también funciona. Gracias.