# construir json a partir de mysql recursivo

Tags: php, mysql, json

Necesito:::

```js
var data = {
  "id": 1,
  "puesto": "Director",
  "nombre": "David Mares",
  "hijos": [{
    "id": 2,
    "puesto": "Gerente TI",
    "nombre": "Gustavo Di",
    "hijos": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "puesto": "Gerente Gral",
    "nombre": "Pedro Alonzo",
    "hijos": []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "puesto": "Gerente Ventas",
    "nombre": "Brenda Sanchez",
    "hijos": []
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "puesto": "Gerente Operacion",
    "nombre": "Adrian Davila",
    "hijos": []
  }]
}
```

Debe salir de una consulta a mi tabla en mysql.  Sin embargo lo que tengo es una consulta recursiva CTE en mysql y no sé cómo llevar lo que me retorna a un resultado donde cada padre venga son sus hijos

Tengo:

```html
WITH RECURSIVE d AS
(
   SELECT a.id, a.name AS puesto, a.name AS nombre, a.area_id  
   FROM ctv_gxd_areas a 
   WHERE area_id IS NULL 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT h.id, h.name AS puesto, h.name AS nombre, h.area_id  
   FROM ctv_gxd_areas h INNER JOIN d ON h.area_id = d.id
)
SELECT * FROM d
```

Y el resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el json que retorna:

```html
[{"id":"2","name":"area 1 ","hijo_id":"5","hijo":"area 4"},{"id":"2","name":"area 1 ","hijo_id":"3","hijo":"area 2"},{"id":"3","name":"area 2","hijo_id":"7","hijo":"area 33"},{"id":"4","name":"area 3","hijo_id":"6","hijo":"area 5"},{"id":"5","name":"area 4","hijo_id":null,"hijo":null},{"id":"6","name":"area 5","hijo_id":"9","hijo":"area 55"},{"id":"7","name":"area 33","hijo_id":"8","hijo":"area 333"},{"id":"8","name":"area 333","hijo_id":null,"hijo":null},{"id":"9","name":"area 55","hijo_id":null,"hijo":null}]
```

No es para nada como el que necesito. ¿Cómo hacer el query/consulta para que me retorne un resultado como necesito? ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias

La version de mysql soporta json.  Estoy usando una tabla temporal para guardar el json de los "hijos" el problema es que pueden haber muchos niveles de descendientes, me explico: hijos, nietos, bisnietos y así

```html
INSERT INTO DBarrays(id, area_id, json_aa) (
SELECT id, area_id, JSON_ARRAY(CONCAT('{', 
        '"id": "', COALESCE(d.id, ''), '", ',
        '"nombre": "', REPLACE(COALESCE(d.name, ''), '"', '\\"'), '", '
        '"id_area": "', REPLACE(COALESCE(d.area_id, ''), '"', '\\"'), '", '
      '}'))
       FROM areas AS d);

SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_aa) AS attributes 
       FROM DBarrays GROUP BY id, area_id;
```

El area_id me indica de quién es hijo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de MySQL? A partir de una determinada versión puedes obtener resultados JSON. Y, si no soporta esa posibilidad, puedes crear el JSON como cadena, a mano, mediante el uso de `GROUP_CONCAT`, de `CONCAT` y otros para generar tu salida tal cual la necesitas sin necesidad de tener que manipularla por programación.

Comment: Yo tenía un problema parecido y como mi versión de MySQL no soporta JSON, opté por construirlo desde la consulta, gracias a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140513/29967) de @Marcos. Creo que lo explicado allí y lo planteado en la pregunta te puede dar una pista, en caso de que tu MySQL no soporte JSON.

Comment: @A. Cedano gracias por tu respuesta, si soporta el json.  He estado trabajando con eso, pero como puede tener muchos niveles o muchos hijos, cada registro estoy algo confundida.  Estoy usando (lo detallaré en la pregunta)